# How to URL encode a long text?

Tags: paw-app

how can I enter a 2KB formatted TXT (line breaks) that should get URL-Encoded? Just pasting it into the input line doesn't work as the result is not formatted in any way.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z934uvy6bjz98e3/Screenshot%202016-04-13%2014.28.16.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a really complex text, I recommend you to just keep the text in a plain text file somewhere in your disk, and use a *File Dynamic Value* to reference it, and wrap the whole thing in your *URL-Encode Dynamic Value*.

Some steps:

1. Create a file with your content
2. In your *URL-Encode dynamic value*, right-click on the *Input* field and pick File > File Content

[image: Pick a file reference in Paw]

3. Click on the newly created *File (Not specified)* token, and you'll be prompted to either pick or drag-and-drop a file
4. You should be good to go. And whenever the file changes, you can send the request, and it should be up-to-date, it's just a pointer to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use proper URL encoding, the linebreaks `\n` should be encoded as `%0A`. This

```
foo
bar
baz
```

will be encoded as

```
foo%0Abar%0Abaz%0A
```